# Estimation of Conditional Expectation

Tags: python, inference, conditional-expectation

I have two independent random variables $X$ and $Y$. I have data for both $X$ and $Y$. Based on the data I want to empirically estimate the value of $E(X|X>Y)$. Please suggest how to proceed.

Comment: Example in `R`: `mean(x[x > y])`.  But this makes assumptions about the data; for instance, that they are paired.  That's why generally we need more details from you.